# Steam gaming on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: games, steam

I wanted to install linux ubuntu but the only thing holding me back is the gaming support in steam. I was wondering if i should go with the latest LTS version 16.04 however all resources* I have found has stated to use 12.04 LTS instead and not sure if installing this would be good if it will be obsolete in 6 months?

*Valve:

1. https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1504-QHXN-8366&l=

*Ubuntu wiki:

3. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve

Im not really interested in doing a 'hacky' install of steam if ubuntu 16.04 unless it is supported by now? Could someone help me in picking the right ubuntu version to install?

Comment: It's perfectly supported and also available at the repositories. Just open your Ubuntu Software or, in terminal, *sudo apt install steam*

Answer (score 3):

The 64-bit version of Steam on the Steam website is currently not functioning correctly on 64-bit 16.04 LTS systems (login loop). However, like CelticWarrior said, the 32-bit version from the repository "multiverse" is perfectly functional and supported. Make sure you have the repository "multiverse" enabled, and then:

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

or,

```
sudo apt install steam
```

Also, don't fret that you have a 32-bit version of Steam. Games that are 64-bit will be installed as such.

I don't recommend gaming on linux at the moment. Unless you're running a nVidia card, AMD and Intel OpenGL support is terrible and, in general, DirectX, under Windows, is a lower-level, faster, and better API. I dearly hope this changes with the introduction of Vulkan.

I would love to run games like CS:GO properly under linux (doesn't render fullscreen, ~20% fps hit, etc.), as well as future games that may utilize Vulkan. However, I don't see this at the moment. Stick to Windows for gaming. On a side note, it also has easier and more efficient support for gaming keyboards.